# Accessing parent properties in UserControls from different aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, aspx-user-control

There is a aspx page which makes use of UserControl as follows.

Page1.aspx.cs

```
public class Page1
{
  public string Code {get;set;}
 ....

}
```

In the Page1.aspx a user control called "UsrControl"

```
<@Register TagPrefix="Usr" NameSpace="UsrControl">
```

I have the following code in UsrControl.

```
 public class UsrControl : Label
    {
      private Page1 _page1;
      
     protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
      {
        _page1 = (Page1)Page;
        string test = _page1.Code;
      }
.....
    }
```

In the usercontrol , the parent page is harcoded and from there the property of parent page (**Page1**) is being used .

Now the thing is I have one more aspx page **Page2** which has same set of properties as Page1(**Code**) needed to invoke "**UsrControl**"

How can I refactor "**UsrControl**" to have the capability of accepting **Page1** and **Page2** and execute the code ? Should reflection be used?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to turn it around. Set the `Code` value from the page to the UserControl instead of getting it from the Page.

So in your UserControl add a property `Code`

```
public string Code { get; set; }
```

Then you can set that property from the aspx page of the parent.

```
<Usr:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" Code='<%# Code %>' />
```

And then call `DataBind();` in `Page_Load` of the parent page.

```
public string Code { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Code = "This is a test.";

    DataBind();
}
```

You can also add the UserControl programatically on the parent page and set `Code` from there.

```
public WebUserControl1 UsrControl { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Code = "This is a test.";

    UsrControl = (WebUserControl1)LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx");
    UsrControl.Code = Code;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(UsrControl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make an interface that shapes your data provider

```
public class IPageDataProvider
{
  string Code {get;set;}
}
```

and implement this interface in both your pages

```
public class Page1 : IPageDataProvider
{
  public string Code {get;set;}
  ....

}

public class Page2 : IPageDataProvider
{
  public string Code {get;set;}
  ....

}
```

After that, refactor your user control

```
public class UsrControl : Label
{
  private IPageDataProvider _pageDataProvider;
  
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
  {
    this._pageDataProvider = this.Page as IPageDataProvider;
    if ( this._pageDataProvider != null )
    {
      string test = this._pageDataProvider.Code;
    }
    else
    {
      // parent page doesn't implement the interface
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not allowed to introduce a interface for Page1 to implement.